# Message: Unable to locate element - Follow Button Instagram Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to create a bot to hit a button in the browser, in another window hit the follow button instagram and go back to the first window. And It's ok to switch windows, but I can't did the bot press the follow button in instagam (I created a bot independent only for hit the follow button and ok but don't work in the new script). Where am I wrong? The code:

```
window_after = browser.window_handles[2]

time.sleep(10)

seguir = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button').click()

browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
```

The error:

```
Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button
```

I tried css selector but is the same error.

Comment: can you perovide url or DOM to check which element you are trying to handle?

Comment: yes, you can login in instagram and try to follow anyone profile like this: [link] (https://www.instagram.com/instagram/)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to handle list of all follow buttons then you can usebelow xpath

```
//button[contains(text(),'Follow')]
```

Also you can handle speciific based on profile, so in that case you can use index

```
(//button[contains(text(),'Follow')])[index]
```

**example:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[contains(text(),'Follow')])[1]"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: check example and note section from answer

Comment: If you happy witth the answer then please accept answer for a closure

Comment: I'm happy but I don't know what happened now, in cmd: `line 79, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(browser,60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[contains(text(),'Follow')])[1]"))).click()` and `line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` I put 60 seconds and the error persists

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing on sites but xpath is 100% correct

Comment: Yes man, and a I create a bot for hit the same Button but don't work in this script